# Copiar texto con fuente de letra

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo el siguiente código java de lo cual permite escribir y mostrar el texto escrito.Todo funciona bien pero el problema es que no se copia el estilo o tipo de lecha o diseño de la letra (font), quiero que cuando presiono el boton copiar tambien copie el estilo de la letra para cuando lo pegue en otro lugar se mantenga el diseño de la letra. Actual muestra el texto por defecto.

```
btnGenerarDiseñoletra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtMostrarNombre1.setText(editTextNombre.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    btnCopiar = findViewById(R.id.btnCopiar);
    btnCopiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("TextView", txtMostrarNombre1.getText());
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Copiado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que los tipos de fuente no se pegan (al estilo copiar/pegar). Lo que debes hacer cuando pegas el texto, es setear el tipo de fuente al nuevo contenedor (`TextView` supongo)  en el que vas a pegar el texto.

Comment: Quiero que mi app sea como la de esta web https://www.ligadegamers.com/generador-nicks-simbolos-letras-especiales/